# Running WP_Query in a class causes unnamed WP_Query Object

Tags: php, wordpress, class, oop

I have to run a number of queries and alter the values returned depending on some user meta.
I decided to level up and try and do this using object oriented programming so I have a class to retrieve the data and I am planning to make classes that inherent and alter the data depending on user meta.

Originally I had my instance of WP_Query called from a procedural function and it gave me this Output:

```
BreakFastQuery from FunctionWP_Query Object
```

When I replicate the function inside my class I get this output:

```
WP_Query Object
```

The content of the two objects are identical but since the second object is an unnamed instance I cannot access it and my loop returns no posts despite the fact that there are post objects contained within this instance of WP_Query

Here is the class that contains the function with the query and the loop.

Does anybody know how I can access the contents of the object this instance of WP_Query generates or alternatively give the instance a variable name that I can reference. I had assumed that the query would work in exactly the same way inside the class and therefore my instance of WP query would be called $meal_type_query. Instead $meal_type_query contains the unnamed instance of WP_Query and ruins my day.

```
class mealQuery {



function __construct( $query_type ) {
    $this->dietPlanQuery( $query_type );
}



      public function dietPlanQuery ( $mealType ) {
        $ids = get_field($mealType);

        $meal_type_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'         => 'recipe',
        'posts_per_page'    => 4,
        'post__in'          => $ids,
        'post_status'       => 'any',
        'orderby'       => 'post__in',
        ));


        // The Loop
        if ( $meal_type_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while ( $meal_type_query->have_posts() ) {
                $meal_type_query->the_post();
                echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        } else {
            // no posts found
            echo 'FAIL';
        }
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();





        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($meal_type_query);
        echo '</pre>';
//close dietPlanQuery
    }
//close the class
}
```

Comment: Can u give a sample of how are you instantiating this class and passing the paramter to the function inside?

Comment: and by the way, `get_field()` function expects post ID as a paramter too. It's missing so maybe that's why you are getting blank data.

Comment: $breakfastQuery = new mealQuery( 'breakfast_recipes' );

This is in the template for the page.
I'm able to print_r the contents of $meal_type_query but I can't access the posts inside the WP_Query instance that it contains.

Comment: What do you mean by "unnamed instance of WP_Query"? What output do you expect and what are you getting?

Comment: print_r(); results in:

        WP_Query Object

As opposed to:

        BreakFastQuery from FunctionWP_Query Object

Both contain the same data but I can't access the data in the first object as it has no variable name to refer to

Answer (score 0):

Remove the function call from the `constructor` and call the function manually.

```
class mealQuery {



function __construct( ) {
//Do nothing
}



  public function dietPlanQuery ( $mealType ) {
    $ids = get_field($mealType);

    $meal_type_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'recipe',
    'posts_per_page'    => 4,
    'post__in'          => $ids,
    'post_status'       => 'any',
    'orderby'       => 'post__in',
    ));

    /* Comment the loop since it will be used later
    // The Loop
    if ( $meal_type_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $meal_type_query->have_posts() ) {
            $meal_type_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        // no posts found
        echo 'FAIL';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
    loop ends */





    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($meal_type_query);
    echo '</pre>';
    //close dietPlanQuery
    }
     //close the class
     }
```

And then call the function like this:

```
$instance = new mealQuery();
$myData = $instance->dietPlanQuery('hi');
print_r($myData);
```

This will hold your data.
And to loop through that, you can use the WP_Query loop like usual:

```
if ( $myData->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $myData->have_posts() ) {
        $myData->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
   echo 'FAIL';
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I can print_r the data but it is in an unnamed instance of WP_Query so I can't access the post objects that it contains. I can just view them when I print_r($meal_type_query);

The data is contained within an instance of WP_Query but the instance is unnamed

Comment: Thanks for trying. That does hold the data but the data is still held in an object called WP_Query Object.

I can't access that data at the moment.
The result is essentially the same as I can't access the posts inside that object because it doesn't have a variable name.

I'm trying to assign it a variable name like this:
        BreakFastQuery from FunctionWP_Query Object
That's what I get if I call it from a regular function.

Alternatively I need to find the syntax to access the post data contained in that WP_Query Object.

Comment: Why can't you access the data when you have it inside the object? How are you trying to access it exactly?

Comment: @LosBenos see the updated answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly the solution I had at the beginning.

For some reason it just shows that my object is an empty object.
I've managed to access the data in the object using this code:

`         foreach ($this->meal_query->query as &$meals) {
            echo '<pre>';
                print_r($meals);
            echo '</pre>';`

But now I need to get in to the arrays contained within...

You can see the output here:
[link](https://nutrasure.co.uk/diet-plans/)

Comment: I'm going to hook up with a friend on Sunday and we will figure out exactly what is going on and then post the answer in this thread.
Thanks a lot for all your time bro

Comment: What I mean to say is that you can use the regular QP_Query loop on the object returned by your class method like I have done in the updated answer/

Comment: That returns no posts but I'll solve it later today and post an update.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help guys but apparently you just can't help stupid.
This turned out to be entirely user error.
    $ids = get_field($mealType);
Should have been:
    $ids = get_field($mealType, false, false);

I misread the documentation and thought that the default values were false so I didn't include them.
It actually defaults to true which meant that my query was essentially malformed and that's why I couldn't access the data in the usual way.
Apologies.
Thanks for all your help.
It turns out you were totally right, I just messed up when accessing meta from ACF.